# Cannot download file from Google Storage inside Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Im trying to perform a simple download of a .docx file info a buffer so I can handle it latter inside my Cloud Function. I've been using the whole Google Platform for multiple projects but never faced the need to download in server side, and now I need to, I just cant.

The following piece of code is not working, it just sends timeout as a response (I don't even get an error If I try to catch it or something):

```
    var bucket = admin.storage().bucket("gs://myBucket.com");

return bucket.file("001Lineales/4x3-1/1000.docx").download().then((contents)=>{
                var buffer = contents[0];
                //I never get into this point
            }).catch((error)=>{
                //No error
            })
```

I tried in a local NodeJs script and worked as expected. Also tried to perform a `readStream()` download but no luck, the function gets hang up in any try of downloading the file.

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                var archivo = bucket.file(selectedCategory).createReadStream();
                var array = [];
                //Under here, never happens
                archivo.on('data', (d) => {array.push(d)}).on("end",()=>{
                    var newbuff = Buffer.concat(array);
                    resolve(newbuff)
                })
            })
```

The file permissions read/write are public. And the main problem is that debugging is difficult cause Im not able to perform this function in local emulator.

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Double checking a local call with emulator, I get the following error:

```
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

Comment: Can you share your dependencies? (package.json file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the service account hat you've assigned to the Cloud Function and that you've given it the permission it needs.

I think `Storage Object Viewer` will give you what you need to read a file into the buffer.

By default, if you haven't changed it, the AppEngine's default service account gets used, which I don't think has access to Storage.

Comment: This is running inside a cloud function.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But Google products don't all have free access to other products just because it's running inside GCP. That's a bigtime security issue. So you have to explicitly grant permission, and that's done via service accounts. Start here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts It'll explain a bit how they work, and what's likely going on in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, really helpful. I changed service-accounts permissions and now its working.